# cryptsetup: Waiting for encrypted source device after the motherboard has been replacement

Tags: boot, 20.04, encryption, initramfs, cryptsetup

I have a dell xps laptop: the ram was faulty and the motherboard has been replaced.

The problem: My hard drive was encrypted and now I am not able to recover it. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Booting stalls at
`cryptsetup: Waiting for encrypted source device UUID=xxxxxxxxx` and once the BusyBox shell drops and there is little that I can do from the initramfs.

I suspect the solution to be simple, but I am a bit at lost. I tried to boot a from a live USB, but `sudo ldisk -f` doesn't show the encrypted disk. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was the following: after changing the motherboard you need to change the SATA Operation.

By default by the XPS BIOS setting went back to RAID On, whereas I had to bring them back to AHCI. After changing it, the system correctly identified the encrypted disk and allowed me to decrypt it!